# how to customize the width of table cell?

Tags: tables, tabularx

I can not change the whole width of the table, I'd like to know how to enlarge the whole width of the table? Are there any methods automatically changing the the width of table cell based on the number of words(width of text in table cell)
[image]

```
    \documentclass[xcolor=usenames,dvipsnames]{article} % <-- set xcolor options here

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}

\tcbset{tab1/.style={fonttitle=\bfseries\large,fontupper=\normalsize\sffamily,
colback=yellow!10!white,colframe=red!75!black,colbacktitle=Salmon!40!white,
coltitle=black,center title,freelance,frame code={
\foreach \n in {north east,north west,south east,south west}
{\path [fill=red!75!black] (interior.\n) circle (12mm); };},}}

\tcbset{tab2/.style={enhanced,fonttitle=\bfseries,fontupper=\normalsize\sffamily,
colback=yellow!10!white,colframe=red!50!black,colbacktitle=Salmon!40!white,
coltitle=black,center title}}

\begin{document}
%\begin{frame}{皮亚杰和维果斯基关于自我中心言语或自我言语的不同观点}
\begin{tcolorbox}[tab2,tabularx={p{2cm}||p{4.1cm}<{\raggedright}|p{6cm}<{\raggedright}}]
理论假设 & 皮亚杰     & 维果斯基       \\\hline\hline
发展的意义   & 代表儿童还不能接受他人观点，不能与他人交流 & 代表外部思维，它的功能在于自我交流，以实现自我指导和自我定向 \\\hline
发展的进程 & 随着年龄增长逐渐减少 & 年幼时增长，然后逐渐减少，从有声言语转向内部言语 \\\hline
与社会言语的关系  & 消极的；社会化程度和认知成熟度越低的儿童，使用自我中心言语越多 & 积极的；自我言语是从与他人的互动中发展起来的\\\hline
环境背景的影响：任务难度   &  \quad & 随任务难度的增大出现越频繁。在需要付出更多认知努力才能解决问题的情境中，自我言语能够帮助儿童进行自我指导
\end{tcolorbox}
%\end{frame}
%https://www.simplypsychology.org/vygotsky.html
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

a tabularx has to have an `X` column:

[image]

```
    \documentclass[xcolor=usenames,dvipsnames]{article} % <-- set xcolor options here

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}

\tcbset{tab1/.style={fonttitle=\bfseries\large,fontupper=\normalsize\sffamily,
colback=yellow!10!white,colframe=red!75!black,colbacktitle=Salmon!40!white,
coltitle=black,center title,freelance,frame code={
\foreach \n in {north east,north west,south east,south west}
{\path [fill=red!75!black] (interior.\n) circle (12mm); };},}}

\tcbset{tab2/.style={enhanced,fonttitle=\bfseries,fontupper=\normalsize\sffamily,
colback=yellow!10!white,colframe=red!50!black,colbacktitle=Salmon!40!white,
coltitle=black,center title}}

\begin{document}
%\begin{frame}{皮亚杰和维果斯基关于自我中心言语或自我言语的不同观点}
\begin{tcolorbox}[tab2,tabularx={p{2cm}||p{4.1cm}<{\raggedright}|X<{\raggedright}}]
理论假设 & 皮亚杰     & 维果斯基       \\\hline\hline
发展的意义   & 代表儿童还不能接受他人观点，不能与他人交流 & 代表外部思维，它的功能在于自我交流，以实现自我指导和自我定向 \\\hline
发展的进程 & 随着年龄增长逐渐减少 & 年幼时增长，然后逐渐减少，从有声言语转向内部言语 \\\hline
与社会言语的关系  & 消极的；社会化程度和认知成熟度越低的儿童，使用自我中心言语越多 & 积极的；自我言语是从与他人的互动中发展起来的\\\hline
环境背景的影响：任务难度   &  \quad & 随任务难度的增大出现越频繁。在需要付出更多认知努力才能解决问题的情境中，自我言语能够帮助儿童进行自我指导
\end{tcolorbox}
%\end{frame}
%https://www.simplypsychology.org/vygotsky.html
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I want to accurately control the width of table cell and enlarge the whole width of the table, what can I do?

Comment: @dozer I'm not sure what you mean. The example has some columsn where the width is set (by you) eg `p{2cm}` makes the text in the first column 2cm wide, then the final X column puts all the remaining with into the last column. tcolorbox will have width options for specifying the target width